# Last value from POST array to another page

Tags: php, html, forms, select

I got problems to get the correct array values from the form.

I have that code where i invoke the form option value 3 times. That is defined in database. I have one example what is in the database now in the following picture:

[image]

When i press the button "Submeter" redirect to another page where is giving the echo what is passing the array.

teste.php

```
<?php
   $option = isset($_POST['corp_resp']) ? $_POST['corp_resp'] : false;
   if ($option) {
      print_r ($_POST['corp_resp']);
   } else {
     echo "task option is required";
     exit; 
   }
```

Output given:

```
Array ( [0] => 0.75 )
```

The output i need to get:

```
Array ( [0] => 0.25 [1] => 0.50 [2] => 0.75 )
```

Code where is the form:

```
echo("<tr>

    <td align=\"center\" bgcolor='FFFFFF'>$id</td>
    <td align=\"center\"  bgcolor='FFFFFF'> 
        <form id=\"teste\" method=\"post\" action=\"teste.php\"> 
        <select name='corp_resp[]'\>;
            <option value=\"0\">0</option>;
            <option value=\"0.05\">0.05</option>;
            <option value=\"0.1\">0.1</option>;
            <option value=\"0.15\">0.15</option>;
            <option value=\"0.20\">0.20</option>;
            <option value=\"0.25\">0.25</option>;
            <option value=\"0.30\">0.30</option>;
            <option value=\"0.35\">0.35</option>;
            <option value=\"0.40\">0.40</option>;
            <option value=\"0.45\">0.45</option>;
            <option value=\"0.50\">0.50</option>;
            <option value=\"0.55\">0.55</option>;
            <option value=\"0.60\">0.60</option>;
            <option value=\"0.65\">0.65</option>;
            <option value=\"0.70\">0.70</option>;
            <option value=\"0.75\">0.75</option>;
            <option value=\"0.80\">0.80</option>;
            <option value=\"0.85\">0.85</option>;
            <option value=\"0.90\">0.90</option>;
            <option value=\"0.95\">0.95</option>;
            <option value=\"1.0\">1</option>;

        </select>

        <br><br>
        </center>

        </form>
```

The code from the button:

```
echo ('<input type="submit" name="corp_resp[]" value="Submeter"  class="link-style2" />');
```

Comment: Please learn modern HTML and CSS. Tables for layout were considered a bad idea before the turn of the century. The `align` & `bgcolor` attributes and the `centre` element are obsolete. The `br` element isn't intended to be used to fake margins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can improve your code by generating the `<select>`s dynamically from database :

```
<form id="teste" method="post" action="teste.php"> 

<?php
$con = mysqli_connect( "localhost","root","","database_name" ); // ◄■ CONNECT TO DATABASE.
$dat_menuid = mysqli_query( $cnn,"select * from my_table" ) // ◄■ MENUIDs.
                      or die( mysqli_error($con) );
$options = array( "0.25","0.50","0.75" ); // ◄■■ OPTIONS ARE STATIC (ALWAYS THE SAME).
while ( $row_menuid = mysqli_fetch_array( $data ) ) // ◄■ DISPLAY <SELECT>s.
{ echo "<select name='corp_resp&{$row_menuid["id"]}'>\n"; // ◄■■ CORP_RESP&1,CORP_RESP&2.
  foreach ( $options as $opt ) // ◄■■ DISPLAY OPTIONS.
    echo "<option value='$opt'>$opt</option>\n";
  echo "</select>\n"; // ◄■■ SELECT END.
}
?>
        <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

Explanation : each `<select>` has the name "corp_resp&" and the menuid (4, 5, 6), so the names are "corp_resp&4", "corp_resp&5", "corp_resp&6", etc. All selects have the same options. Notice previous code gets the menuids from database, so it will display as many `<select>` as menuids are.

Now "teste.php" will insert like this :

```
<?php
   if ( isset($_POST) ) {
   foreach ( $_POST as $key => $value )
      { $cr = explode( "&",$key ); // ◄■■ SPLIT : [0]="CORP_RESP",[1]="1".
        mysqli_query( $con,"insert into my_table (menuid,corp_resp) " .
                                        "values ('{$cr[1]}','$value')" );
      }
   } else {
     echo "task option is required";
     exit; 
   }
?>
```

Explanation : all the names in $_POST are splitted, example : "corp_resp&4" becomes $cr[0] ("corp_resp") and $cr[1] ("4"). This number is used as the id for the selected option.

Comment: Is not in that way i need.

Comment: Hello @Jose Manuel, that $data is for which variable? Because is not defined and you tell in comments is for display the select i presume is $options?

Comment: Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, array given in C:\ and is given that error.

Comment: Your idea is very good. But is not working yet like i told you. Is two problems... Give 7 select`s and the submit for each one.

Comment: Yes i know that. But where need to be because can not be inside of the form. Repeat all the time.

Comment: @Manuel Abarca Rodriguez, Is generating all the <select> in database not only 4,5,6. The only thing i change was {$row_menuid['menuId'] because {$row_menuid['id'] don´t exist. Was the only difference from your code. Please check the mail.

Comment: @Manuel Abarca Rodriguez I try to use that query SELECT * FROM menu WHERE $id = menuIdPai  ORDER BY menuId , for select only what is from menuIdPai, but don´t work either.

Comment: @Manuel Abarca Rodriguez I change for that "SELECT * FROM menu WHERE menuId = '".$menuId."'"  and is working, now the problem is the submit, where i need to put?

Comment: @Manuel Abarca Rodriguez. Yes.

Comment: @Manuel Abarca Rodriguez. That is given 3 submit`s and i need only one for submit all.

Comment: @Manuel, i solve already. I put outside of the form without name and is working. Now i am in the last part to insert the data correct in database. Let see if is all right.

Comment: Your example is inserting correct but i want to add more values   mysqli_query( $con,"insert into respostas (id_resp,corp_resp,data,id) . How is posible to do that? That values comes out of the table.

Comment: @ChristopheCosta, you can add those values to the <form> that contains the <select>s, those values will be sent to teste.php and so they can be inserted in database. You add values to the form as <input type='text' name='something'>.

Comment: Thank you. You really help me.

Answer (score 3):

You only have one select element in the form.

If you want data from multiple select elements to be submitted together then you need to put them all in the same form.

Move the form start and end tags so they surround the whole table.

Comment: I only submit one value from which form. Form1=0.25 Form2=0.5 Form3=0.75

Comment: @ChristopheCosta Yes, that is why you have the problem you described.

Answer (score 0):

As Quentin said you have only one select but you need three ones.
To achieve what you wrote try to write something like that:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name='corp_resp[0]' >
          <option value="0.85">0.85</option>
          <option value="0.90">0.90</option>
          <option value="0.95">0.95</option>
          <option value="1.0">1</option>
         </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name='corp_resp[1]' >
          <option value="0.85">0.85</option>
          <option value="0.90">0.90</option>
          <option value="0.95">0.95</option>
          <option value="1.0">1</option>
         </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name='corp_resp[2]' >
          <option value="0.85">0.85</option>
          <option value="0.90">0.90</option>
          <option value="0.95">0.95</option>
          <option value="1.0">1</option>
         </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Is possible to do a dynamic select?